# Custom split email column names into multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have an email column with 3-4 emails in each row which i want to split into one email per column:

Current columns looks like this:

```
     Email_column
1. drone@gmail.com bob@yahoo.com drake@gmail.com
```

Expected output should be:

```
    Email_1               Email_2         Email_3
1.  drone@email.com    bob@yahoo.com      drake@gmail.com
```

Comment: sql server or mysql? And why oh why do you have multiple emails stored like this?

Comment: @SeanLange SQL server. Well its an old system and people have been storing values like this which i need to fix now.

Comment: You have to first split this into rows, then you will need a dynamic pivot or dynamic cross tab to spread this into multiple columns.

Comment: Is this SQL 2008, or still the older system? Which version of SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a CROSS APPLY and a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Email_column varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'drone@gmail.com bob@yahoo.com drake@gmail.com')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos4 = n.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(A.Email_column,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1            Pos2            Pos3              Pos4
1   drone@gmail.com bob@yahoo.com   drake@gmail.com   NULL
```